# Alarmmanager wont work after reboot on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, notifications, alarmmanager, reboot

Hi I know this question has been asked before but I dont think it has in this context. I have a application which runs through a DB and then according to times in that DB sets repeating alarms every 24 Hours.

The Alarms work but as soon as I reboot I get one Alarm straight away then no more until I open the app again.

I have the following **two methods** which set up the alarm. The to_reminder method is run from my onCreate method in my main Activity.

```
public void to_reminder()
{
    helper = new TaskDBHelper(Meds2.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK, TaskContract.Columns.DATE},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    //Cancel All Alarms
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,BackgroundService.class);
    AlarmManager manager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(this,
            0,intent, 0);
    try {
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
    }


    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { // Loop until all vales have been seen

        String time = cursor.getString(2);
        String[] parts = time.split(":"); //Split  String Value stored in db
        String part1 = parts[0]; // hour
        String part2 = parts[1]; // minute
        int hr = Integer.parseInt(part1);
        int min = Integer.parseInt(part2);

        Random generator = new Random();

        setUpAlarm(hr,min);

        Log.e(TAG, "DATE VALUE TIME IS " + part1 +"--" +part2 + " Random Number is: " + generator.nextInt()); //log part one and two to make sure time is right
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}

public void setUpAlarm(int hr, int min){

    Random generator = new Random();
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,BackgroundService.class);

    AlarmManager manager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(this,
            generator.nextInt(),intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    long _alarm = 0;

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    if(cal.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
        _alarm = cal.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY+1);
    else
        _alarm = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

}
```

My **Alarm Receiver** Class simply starts BackgroundService

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);

    context.startService(background);
}
```

}

My **Background service** sets up the notification.

```
public void mainMeth(){


    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(this,Meds2.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            browserIntent,
            0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cast_ic_notification_2)
                    .setContentTitle("Medication Reminder")
                    .setContentInfo("Time")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentText("Open Application" )
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{200, 200, 200, 200}) //set virbrate & color of led
                    .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000);

    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(getID(), builder.build());

}
```

My **Manifest** has the following code in it too

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Any help on how I can get this to work after a reboot would be appreciated thanks.